# How to detect a click and manipulate element in my case

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to detect a document click when user clicks anywhere in the page . I also want to prevent clicking a div to trigger the document clicks.

I have something like

```
//Directive for page click
angular.module('myApp').directive('documentClick', ['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(e){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('pageClick');
            })
        }
}]);

controller JS

  //within a controller
  $scope.toggleDiv = function() {
      $scope.openDiv = !$scope.OpenDiv;
   }

  $scope.$on('pageClick', function($event) {
            $scope.openDiv = false;
  })

html 
  <body document-click>
      <div ng-controller = 'ctrl'>
          <div id='testDiv'>
               <div id='childDiv' ng-click="toggleDiv()">
                    toggle div here
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

I don't want to trigger `$scoep.openDiv = false` when I click '`childDiv`'. I only want to trigger `$scope.openDiv = false` when I click anywhere in the page.

Is there an angular way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass down the event `e` and check the `target.id`:

`$rootScope.$broadcast('pageClick', e);`

```
$scope.$on('pageClick', function($event, e) {
    if(e.target.id !== 'childDiv')
        $scope.openDiv = false;
})
```